# is it possible to create user in AWS SSO programmtically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on

is it possible to create user in AWS SSO programmtically?
all the I founnd is list users, but not create.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no API for AWS SSO yet to permit this.

However, you can achieve this functionality by connecting an IDP (Okta, AzureAD) to AWS SSO that supports SCIM and then programmatically insert users into the IDP.

Answer (score 1):

AWS now offers CLI & SDK support for user management.

For example:

- [`aws identitystore create-user`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/identitystore/create-user.html)
- [`aws identitystore update-user`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/identitystore/update-user.html)
- [`aws identitystore delete-user`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/identitystore/delete-user.html)

You'll find the same support in the AWS SDKs (and better usage guidance IMO). [For example, here's `create_user` in the Python boto3 AWS SDK](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/identitystore/client/create_user.html).

While AWS SSO groups, permission sets, and assignments (i.e. mappings of users+groups+permission sets to specific accounts) are supported in CloudFormation, AWS SSO users are sadly not supported at the time of this writing.

Shameless plug, that's exactly why I just posted this CDK project example that provides a custom CloudFormation resource with AWS SDK to manage AWS SSO users: https://github.com/matwerber1/aws-cdk-sso-user-management

I've been using it with AWS SSO acting as my identity provider, haven't tried it with external SAML providers. I haven't added support for all of the user attributes supported by the native `create-user` / `update-user` APIs, but you could extend it if needed.

If you use AWS CloudFormation instead of AWS CDK, you should be able to copy-paste my Lambda function's source code and [use it as a custom resource provider directly in your CloudFormation templates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html).